# Height and width attribute not setting by the_post_thumbnail

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I am using following code to display images in home page:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail('postbox-thumb')
```

But the output of the above code does not have height and width of the img tag.
Please help me in solving this problem.

Current sample output:

```
<img alt="Kiran inspects coal mine" class="attachment-postbox-thumb wp-post-image" src="http://i0.wp.com/www.indiahelpdesk.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/HY09-KIRAN_1170869f.jpg?resize=229%2C150">
```

img height and width attributes are missing.

Comment: Why do you need these attributes? If they are not given, the original size of the image is used.

Comment: For better performance I need these attributes.

Comment: According to W3C (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.7.1) you don't need them, except you want to overwrite them. And tbh I can't see why they should boost your page performance. If you want to improve your overall page performance, you should start somewhere else then the image attributes.
If you still want to use them, see my answer below.

Comment: I am following pagespeed recommendations

Answer (score 4):

In the 2nd attribute of `the_post_thumbnail()` you can give additional attributes for the image.

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'postbox-thumb', array( 'width' => 100, 'height' => 100 ) )
```

I've just checked it again the width and height are set in the latest WP Versions,
so you might have just to update your WordPress installation.

Answer (score 0):

Check the parameters for [`the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail#Thumbnail_Sizes) Thumbnail Sizes

```
the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 100) );
```

Or you can add a custom image size for featured images using [`add_image_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#For_Featured_Images) in your function file which includes the width and height

```
add_image_size( 'postbox-thumb', 100, 100, TRUE );
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all add theme support for post-thumbnails with the following "function.php"

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

then add image size with the following code "function.php"

`add_image_size( 'portfolio', 600, 600, true );`

use both of these inside a function which you have to hook into

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'prefix_theme_setup' );
```

now inside the loop check for the post thumbnail

```
has_post_thumbnail()
```

then call the post thumbnail

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio' );
```

you can also set a class attribute and give custom height and width in css, keep width and height equal to the height and width set in add_image_size(); or keep the same ration.

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio', array( 'class' => 'custom-class img-responsive' ) );
```

now you can give custom css class in your css

```
.custom-class { width: 200px; height: 200px; }
```

complete code for function.php

```
/*
 * theme setup
========================================*/
if ( ! function_exists( 'prefix_theme_setup' ) ) :
function prefix_theme_setup() {

    /*
     * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'portfolio', 600, 600, true );

}
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'prefix_theme_setup' );
```

complete code for template file

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
    the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolio', array( 'class' => 'custom-class img-responsive' ) );
endif; ?>
```

:-)